# JavaScript array if one element same takes another element in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I want to convert one array to new format

This is my array

```
let data = [
 { operatorName: 'MBC', negativeTotal: -5873, postiveTotal: 15632 },
 { operatorName: 'OSEN+', negativeTotal: -4071, postiveTotal: 2206 }
];
```

Here I want to covert `data` to this format

Expected Array result:

```
[
    {
        data : [2206, -4071],
        label:'OSEN+'
    },
    {
        data : [15632,-5873],
        label:'MBC'
    }
];
```

I tried this code:

```
const uniqueOperators = [...new Set(data.map((x) => x.operatorName))];
let d = []
let dataset = uniqueOperators.map((uniqueOperator) => {
  
  data.find((item)=>{
    if(item.operatorName === uniqueOperator){
      console.log(item)
    }
    
  })
});
```

But it is not coming what my expected array result.

Comment: Your question is poorly worded. Are you asking how to make an array where each element has a unique `operatorName`? If so, when there is more than one array element with the same `operatorName`, what do you want to do? Pick the first one? The last one? Does it matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would also work. Same as @Mamun's answer with destructuring the items:

```js
let data = [
  { operatorName: "MBC", negativeTotal: -5873, postiveTotal: 15632 },
  { operatorName: "OSEN+", negativeTotal: -4071, postiveTotal: 2206 },
];

const output = data.map(({ operatorName, negativeTotal, postiveTotal }) => ({
  data: [postiveTotal, negativeTotal],
  label: operatorName,
}));

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let data = [{
    operatorName: 'MBC',
    negativeTotal: -5873,
    postiveTotal: 15632
  },
  {
    operatorName: 'OSEN+',
    negativeTotal: -4071,
    postiveTotal: 2206
  }
];
let output = data.map((e) => {
  let obj = {
    data: [e.postiveTotal, e.negativeTotal],
    label: e.operatorName
  }
  return obj;
})

console.log(output);
```